# using wml variable in php code

Tags: php, wml

I wrote the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<wml>
<card>
 title : <input type="text" name="title" /><br/>
 body : <input type="text" name="body" /><br/>
<?php 
echo $(title)
?>
</card>
</wml>
```

the problem How I print the entered value in input text inside php code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to define a form in your markup if you want the input fields to do anything. The form should have an `action` and a `method` attribute.

Then you can use the `$_GET` or `$_POST` superglobal arrays to access the data in the following manner:

```
echo $_POST['title'];
```

Comment: you are right,but I enter a big text in the input text so it's difficult using $_Get ,and $_Post dosn't support in my wap version.is there way to put them in one file ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the content of a variable directly in the screen of the device (or printer if it is an extended WML browser) you need to do it like this:

$(varName)

In your sample you are setting the value from a server variable, not from the device's memory.

A bit late answer but may help someone, WML is not so common anymore but still it is being used for banking and other kind of automated dispensers.